# Know when a database has been restored

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, restore

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I would like to know if a specific database has been restored from a device and when did it happened. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7):

In the msdb database, there is a table named restorehistory:

```
declare @DB sysname = 'MyDB';
select * from msdb.dbo.restorehistory where destination_database_name = @DB;
```

This is a table that people with sufficient privileges can clear out, but if the restore was recent and you don't have a job which clears out this table (or if it hasn't run between then and now), you should be able to see the login which performed the restore.

**EDIT**

You can also join it to a couple of other tables (if they have relevant data):  backupset and backupmediafamily.  If there are records there--with the same retention caveats as before--they'll tell you more about the backup file(s) used to restore:

```
declare @DB sysname = 'MyDB';
select
    rh.destination_database_name,
    rh.user_name,
    bs.name as backup_set_name,
    bs.user_name as backup_set_username,
    bs.backup_start_date,
    bs.backup_finish_date,
    bs.database_name as backup_set_database_name,
    bs.server_name,
    bs.machine_name,
    bmf.physical_device_name,
    bmf.device_type,
    case bmf.device_type
        when 2 then 'Disk'
        when 5 then 'Tape'
        when 7 then 'Virtual Device'
        when 105 then 'Permanent backup device'
        else 'UNKNOWN'
    end as device_type_desc
from 
    msdb.dbo.restorehistory rh
    left outer join msdb.dbo.backupset bs on rh.backup_set_id = bs.backup_set_id
    left outer join msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf on bs.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id
where
    rh.destination_database_name = @DB;
```

That way, you could also filter on device type or file location.

Answer (score 0):

Backup and restore histories for SQL Server 2008 are stored in the **msdb** database **restorehistory** table. You can query it like so:

```
SELECT 
      [restore_history_id]
      ,[restore_date]
      ,[destination_database_name]
      ,[user_name]
      ,[backup_set_id]
      ,[restore_type]
      ,[replace]
      ,[recovery]
      ,[restart]
      ,[stop_at]
      ,[device_count]
      ,[stop_at_mark_name]
      ,[stop_before]
  FROM [msdb].[dbo].[restorehistory]
```