# Capture when any database is restored on the server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, restore

Is there any way that I can identify when a database is restored on the server? I created a server trigger but only triggers when I create a new database not after is restored from another one.

I'm using SQL Server 2014, trying to achieve this using MSMS, using msdb.dbo.restorehistory is good but I don't want to create a job for that, trying to find something straightforward

I want to know as s DBA when any database is created or restored, just for control.

I found that there is no DDL trigger for RESTORE, there is however Event Notification for the AUDIT_BACKUP_RESTORE_EVENT but I didn't find any good example of how to use it.

could someone tell me which accounts I need to merge? I'm confuse, I did it with my account on stackoverflow and it says is already linked and I can't continue

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: I wrote an answer about using Event Notifications for backups some time ago - It could be tweaked to monitor restores - http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/153598/60085

Answer (score 3):

Under the assumption that you are using SQL Server, you can create a trigger against the `msdb..restorehistory` table.

Go ahead and query that table to see what information is in there; I think you can achieve what you are doing.

See [Know when a database has been restored](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29772/sql-server-how-to-know-when-a-database-has-been-restored)

Comment: +1 Of course one small gotcha with that approach is rows can be inserted into msdb.dbo.restorehistory when performing various `RESTORE` operations such as 'RESTORE VERIFYONLY` etc.